# Redirect users with friendly urls htaccess php

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, friendly-url

I need a hand to redirect and write nice urls for my product requests.

So for any request like

https://www.domain.com.au/pages/product.php?product=PRODUCTNAME

Redirect and rewrite to

https://www.domain.com.au/pages/product/PRODUCTNAME

I actually have:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301,NE]
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
# Add trailing slash to url
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(\.[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,5}|/|#(.*))$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1/ [R=301,L]
# Remove .php-extension from url
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)/$ $1.php 
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+(.+?)\.php[\s?] [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1/ [R=301,NE,L]
# End of Apache Rewrite Rules
```

So it goes to:
https://www.domain.com.au/pages/product/?product=PRODUCTNAME

That, for pages like about.php etc it's fine as you may realize.
Thanks ahead!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following to shorten your Product URLs :

Put the following at top of your /root/. htaccess file.

```
RewriteEngine On
#redirect /pages/product.php?product=name to /pages/product/name
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /pages/product\.php\?product=([^\s]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /pages/product/%1? [L,R=301]
 #Rewrite the new URL to the old one
#load the contents from the OLD URL
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^pages/product/([^/]+)/?$ /pages/product.php?product=$1 [L]
```

Comment: Thanks! 
Works well with www.domain.com.au/pages/product/productname/ links but for whatever other condition or the order on the htaccess, this kind of link doesn't rewrite:
https://www.domain.com.au/pages/product/?product=productname
Way to solve that? 


Thanks heaps!

Comment: @Australopythecus For the both links to work , update the condition with this. And clear your browser cache to test the redirection   `RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /pages/product/?(?:\.php)?\?product=([^\s]+) [NC]`

Comment: Doesn't redirect for whatever reason but thanks.

Comment: Another question... galleries are not showing up

Comment: With the old code due to the htaccess modification. Is that possible? How can I pass the variable by parsing the URL? Explode on / then if "product" found get the last part to work as it was????

global $HTTP_POST_VARS;
if (!empty($_GET['product'])) { 
$product = $_GET['product'];
$dirname = '../images/'.$product.'/';

Is this the best option?
$url = $config['self_url'];
$tokens = explode('/', $url);
$product = $tokens[sizeof($tokens)-2];
echo $product;

Comment: I'm having problems with:

Comment: I'm having problems with:

#redirect /pages/index.php?suburb=suburbname to /pages/sitemap/name
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /pages/index\.php\?suburb=([^\s]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /pages/sitemap/%1? [L,R=301]
#Rewrite the new URL to the old one
#load the contents from the OLD URL
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^pages/sitemap/([^/]+)/?$ /pages/index.php?suburb=$1 [L]

Can you give a hand on this? Thanks